# EnvDTE.Expression - Getting the internal name of DataMembers programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsx, envdte, vs-extensibility

Supposing I have the C# code line:

var myList = new List {1,2,3};

And I put "myList" in the Watch window, and then drag the 1st item of the list down, the watch window creates a new line with the internal name of this data member, which in this case would be

(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(myList)).Items[0]

My question is, is there a way to programmatically get this internal name from an EnvDTE's Expression's DataMember?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you just can't. You have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the complete recipe, but I see that `List<T>` has custom attribute `System.Diagnostics.DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute` set with `ProxyTypeName` set to `System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView'1`.  Which, as I understand, means that in the watch windows you actually see that proxy type, not the original one.  Maybe this can point you in the right direction.

To get the attribute I did:

```
myList.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should've mentioned this in the original post, but I already know that. I could do some reverse engineering and inspecting into the debugger attributes, and figure out what the Expression Evaluator is doing, but what I'm asking is if there's a way to get this string directly from Visual Studio's Extensibility  API.

Comment: I don't see any functionality that would be doing exactly that.  I'm working with this API at the moment as well, I think I would've noticed if there was anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, are you using EnvDTE's Expression object, or IDebugProperty2::GetPropertyInfo ? I suspect the latter might yield a solution, but have no idea how to get at that object.